# Can a node.js server know if a server file is created?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

which is the most elegant way or technology to let a **node.js** server know if a file is created on a server?

The idea is: a new image has been created (from a webcam or so) -> dispatch an event!

**UPDATE:** The name of the new file in the directory is not known *a priori* and the file is generated by an external software.

Comment: How is the file being created? If it's node generating the file, that could trigger an event, or maybe another program could notify the node server through IPC.

Comment: The file is generated by an external program

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [`fs.watch()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener). It allows you to "watch" a file or directory and receive events when things change.

***Note:** The documentation states that `fs.watch` is not consistent across platforms, so you should take that in to account before using it.*

```
fs.watch(fileOrDirectoryPath, function(event, filename) {
    // Something changed with filename, trigger event appropriately
});
```

Also something to be aware of from the docs:

> Providing filename argument in the callback is not supported on every
>   platform (currently it's only supported on Linux and Windows). Even on
>   supported platforms filename is not always guaranteed to be provided.
>   Therefore, don't assume that filename argument is always provided in
>   the callback, and have some fallback logic if it is null.

If `filename` is not available on your platform and you're watching a directory you may need to do something where you initially read the directory and cache the list of files in it. Then, when you get an event from `fs.watch`, read the directory again and compare it to the cached list of files to see what was added (if anything).

---

**Update 1:** There's a good module called [watch, on github](https://github.com/mikeal/watch), which makes it easy to watch a directory for new files.

---

**Update 2:** I threw together an example of how to use `fs.watch` to get notified when new files are added to a directory. I think the module I linked to above is probably the better way to go, but I thought it would be nice to have a basic example of how it might work if you were to do it yourself.

***Note:** This is a fairly simplistic example just to show how it could work in general. It could almost certainly be done more efficiently and it's far from throughly tested.*

```
function watchForNewFiles(directory, callback) {
    // Get a list of all the files in the directory
    fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            var originalFiles = files;

            // Start watching the directory for new events
            var watcher = fs.watch(directory, function(event, filename) {
                // Get the updated list of all the files in the directory
                fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err);
                    } else {
                        // Filter out any files we already knew about
                        var newFiles = files.filter(function(f) {
                            return (originalFiles.indexOf(f) < 0);
                        });

                        // Reset our list of "original" files
                        originalFiles = files;

                        // If there are new files detected, call the callback
                        if (newFiles.length) {
                            callback(null, newFiles);
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Then, to watch a directory you'd call it with:

```
watchForNewFiles(someDirectoryPath, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        // handle any newly added files
        // "files" is an array of filenames that have been added to the directory
    }
});
```

Comment: why would you use `fs.watch` is `fs.exists` is available? Also, I think I remember reading somewhere that `fs.watch()` creates files it can't find(I think)

Comment: The question seems to be asking how to detect new files being created. `fs.watch` can do that with OS level APIs and without polling the file system; i.e. it's much more efficient.

Comment: I'll go test that: brb

Comment: Yup, your code doesn't work :P lol FS will just screw stuff up if it can't find the file... [Image](http://s18.postimg.org/i45z35f55/error.png) It does however work well for checking if a file was deleted. :P

Comment: In the case that you're looking for a **new** file, you'd want to watch the directory the file will appear in, not the file itself. I got the impression that the question was regarding a file being created that you might not know the exact name of (say an image from a webcam where the filename increments each time), in which case `fs.exists` won't work. That being said, I'm just offering a possible solution; which method is best will depend on the situation.

Comment: Yes, but watching the directory would cause issues, for example if another person using the service updates the directory... A solution to this would be to have individual directories for each user, which is a hassle-ish...

Comment: Ok... so how do you use `fs.exists` to check for the creation of a file when you don't know the filename ahead of time?

Comment: but he does know the filename ahead of time, also he could just pass in the filename once he knows it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60127/discussion-between-mike-s-and-meaniostack).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with my own solution using this code here:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var intID = setInterval(check,1000);

function check() {
    fs.exists('file.txt', function check(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            console.log("Created!");
            clearInterval(intID);
        }
    });
}
```

You could add a parameter to the check function with the name of the file and call it in the path.

I did some tests on `fs.watch()` and it does not work if the file is not created. `fs.watch()` has multiple issues anyways and I would never suggest using it... It does work to check if the file was deleted though...

Comment: hank you for your suggestion.The idea is more generic, ie: I have a directory. When a new file pops out (you don't know its name, maybe it contains a timestamp or a random string), how can node know?

Comment: you will always know the name, because upon upload you can grab the properties of that file, like the name, or the size.

Comment: Also, if for some reason you do not know the filename, you could use a grab all regex, but that would also update you of all the files on the machine that are being updated by other users in other countries, so I don't suggest it.